# iOS AdMob - Works on production, not on Test Ad

Tags: ios, admob

We're been getting issues recently where test ads never work but production ads work perfectly.

My phone is iPhone 11 pro max, and I'm using Xcode 12.4.
Following guide details from [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads), that's what i've implemented:

1. In the app-ads.txt file i've added google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
2. I'm using adId ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313 for testing purposes
3. In my info.plist file I have SKAdNetworkItems defined with default values from thew guide
4. The dependancy is: s.dependency 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 8.0'
5. I have -ObjC on my build target settings under Other Linker Flags amongst other flags

The error im getting is:

> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s):
> com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network
> adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting
> of your build target.

Again, production ads work great so I don't think its from the implementation itself, it could be that im forgetting something. Regarding test devices, even when I register myself as a test device, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any information.

Comment: @user2168735 it was the app-ads.txt not having the test declaration: google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
read about it here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads?hl=de